# Trying to read JSON from URL and parse into CSV format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, screen-scraping

I am trying to loop through four URLs in a list, scrape the contents of each URL, and save each as a separate CSV. I think my code below is close, but it doesn't really seem to parse the JSON strings into a human-readable format. Also, the headers are missing.

Here is my hacked together code.

```
import urllib
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

all_links = ['https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/474131755_abrazomaranahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=9a27928_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621861138_abrazocavecreekhospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=674fd6f_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621809851_abrazomesahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=13953222_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621811285_abrazosurprisehospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=c8113dcf_2']
for item in all_links:
    #print(item)
    try:
        length = len(item)
        first_under = item.find('_') + 1
        last_under = item.rfind('?') - 21
        file_name = item[first_under:last_under]
        r = requests.get(item)
        print(r.json)
        df = pd.DataFrame(r)
        df.head()
        DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\hospital_data\\' + file_name + '.csv'
        #urllib.request.urlretrieve(df,DOWNLOAD_PATH)
        r = requests.get(item)
        with open(DOWNLOAD_PATH,'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

This is what the data looks like. Is this right? I thought the data would look a lot cleaner if it was converted from JSON to CSV.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, here's what you need to change:

1. You can use pandas dataframes to read json using `df = pd.read_json(text, lines=True)` - for this make sure to specify `lines=True` because some of your data contains `\n` characters
2. You can use the same dataframe to output to a csv using `df.to_csv(file)`

All in all, there are some things in your code that could be removed, e.g. you're calling `requests.get` twice for no real reason, which slows your code down substantially.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

all_links = ['https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/474131755_abrazomaranahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=9a27928_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621861138_abrazocavecreekhospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=674fd6f_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621809851_abrazomesahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=13953222_2',
  'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621811285_abrazosurprisehospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=c8113dcf_2']
for item in all_links:
    try:
        length = len(item)
        first_under = item.find('_') + 1
        last_under = item.rfind('?') - 21
        file_name = item[first_under:last_under]
        r = requests.get(item)
        df = pd.read_json(r.text, lines=True)
        DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\hospital_data\\' + file_name + '.csv'
        with open(DOWNLOAD_PATH,'wb') as f:
            df.to_csv(f)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking for opinion. Is CSV necessary? Or are you just trying to save it in a readable (and preferrably, programmably extractable) format?

Anyways, here is the way to export one result to a `.csv` file:

```py
# Required imports
import json
import csv

"""I am assuming you already made the request and got the response"""
data_set = r.json()   # An iterable of python dict objects
DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\hospital_data\\' + file_name + '.csv'
# (Please take enough care to not reveal personal info above)

# getting the headers
headers = data_set[0].keys()

with open(DOWNLOAD_PATH, "wt", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    
    writer.writerow(headers)    # writing the headers

    for data in data_set:    # writing the values
        write.writerow(data.values())
```

---

And here is the way to export one result to a `.json` file:

```py
import json

data_set = r.json()
DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\hospital_data\\' + file_name + '.json'

with open(DOWNLOAD_PATH, "wt") as file:
    json.dump(data_set, file)
```

You can use whichever file is more readable to you. Note that the above methods were for a single request result. You will have to do the above for each result you extract from the website.

Credits for the CSV method: [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-csv-in-python)